# Generation of 20 random nums in c

Tags: c, random

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{

        int i;
        int array[20];
        srand(time(NULL));
        for (i=0; i<20; i++)
            array[i] = rand()%8999 + 1000;

        char *fname = argv[1];
        FILE *fp;
        fp = fopen(fname,"w");
        fwrite(array,sizeof(int),20,fp );

        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
}
```

my program should generate a sequence of 20 random numbers within a range of 1000 to 9999. I need to create an array of 20 nums, sort it and transfer to the file passed at cmd line... But, it says Segmentation fault

Comment: Could you say exactly what you mean by "it goes wrong"

Comment: and file for example data.txt, after i do ./gen.c data.txt it crates many unknown symbols it it

Comment: I just compiled it (after adding #include <stdlib.h> for srand) and it ran and wrote the file fine.  I didn't get any errors.  The file contains the data but not human readable - you are writing the bytes out and you actually want the human readable values so you should probably be using fprintf

Comment: It writes the contents of the array (20 elements) 20 times. Is that intentional?

Comment: I think the segmentation fault occurred because you forgot to pass the output file name, see my answer to see why.

Comment: Note that this does not generate random numbers. Only pseudo random ones. And the implementation of random is not guaranteed to be any good. It all depend on the usage you want to make of those random numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check the return value of `fopen`.

Then:

```
fwrite(array,sizeof(int),20,fp );
```

You are not moving your `array` pointer. Use something like:

```
fprintf(fp, "%d\n", array[i]);
```

Also:

```
array[i] = rand()%9999 + 1001;
```

What if the value yielded by `rand()%9999` is `9998`? I think then `9998 + 1001` is no longer between `1000` and `9999`. Also how can `rand()%9999 + 1001` yields `1000`?

Comment: Also, choose between *binary* ('wb') or *text* ('w') -- comments suggests the second is what's intended.

Comment: Does he need to?  arrays are contiguous so if he writes starting at array for 20 ints won't he print all the data?

Comment: @AndreyKosyanenko to the next `array` element

Comment: @AndreyKosyanenko: after editing to `rand()%8999 + 1001` it still will not generate "from 1000 to 9999", now it will generate from **1001** to 9999.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah: if you are addressing my '20 times 20' comment, that single `fwrite` is enough *because* arrays are contiguous.

Answer (score 2):

Your formula for getting the random values is also wrong:

With this code:

```
rand()%9999 + 1001;
```

you will get values from **[1001, 11000]**. When you are claiming you want a range from **[1000, 9999]**.

Try to solve this for a simpler case, lets say a dice from **[1, 6]** will be:

```
rand()%5 + 1
```

The other problem is your for loop:

- Remove the for loop and you should be fine. You don't need that for loop to print the array. Check the [rewind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/rewind) function if you really need to do something like that.

Comment: remove the for loop and you should be fine. Otherwise, call [rewind](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/rewind/) function.

Comment: @AndreyKosyanenko Does it still sigfaults?

Answer (score 1):

```
  for (i=0; i<20; i++)
       array[i] = rand()%8999 + 1000; // change random Number logic


   for (i=0; i<20; i++)  

      fprintf(fp,"%d\t",array[i]); // change fwrite(array,sizeof(int),20,fp );
```

see [`fprintf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/printf.html)

Answer (score 1):

First problem, the `rand` calculation is false, if you want an integer between `1000` and `9999`, then it should be :

```
array[i] = rand()%9000 + 1000; // 9000%9000 = 0 ...
```

Then, your call to `fwrite` writes the whole content of the `array` buffer, seen as a set of `sizeof (int)` long substrings. Since odds are quite low that you will end up with valid character encoding, when you will open your file with a text editor to see the results, you will only have gibberish data ... Thus, your whole `for` loop is useless (you will print 20 times the whole content of `array` subsequently to your file).

Here, what you could do is a `for` loop with a call to `fprintf` to write the `array[i]` number in a human readable format or just stick with your single call to `fwrite`.

Then, I would like to say that you do not test the return value of your function calls.
It can be a source of errors so be very careful with this. I think of the whole file operation functions (`fopen`, `fwrite`).

Then, what if `argv[1]` doesn't exist ? When the call to `fopen` will be run, you'll have a segmentation fault ... Here is a little checking you could add :

```
if (argc > 1) {
    fname = argv[1];
} else {
    fname = NULL;
}
```